# socat[10261] E SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations():

Tags: openssl, socat

I was trying to run this command in ubuntu:

`sudo socat -v -v openssl-listen:443,reuseaddr,fork,cert=$FILENAME.pem,cafile=$FILENAME.crt,verify=0 -`

But I got this error message:

`2017/05/17 20:56:12 socat[10268] E SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(): error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory`

I was trying to fix this error and make it work, but it didn't fixed. I hope someone can tell me how to fix it

Comment: Your cert/ca-files exist in the current directory?

Comment: I tried it in here  /etc/ssl/certs but its same problem

Comment: `fopen:No such file or directory` is often a missing OpenSSL configuration file. Try setting `OPENSSL_CONF=<location> socat -v -v openssl ...`. `sudo` may be dropping `OPENSSL_CONF` from the environment (if it was set that way). Maybe `sudo -E` will help.

Answer (score -1):

I think an

> strace -f -e open

Of your socat command would reveal a file not found for your files.

Try to provide the full absolute path.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, later found, I didn't have `cafile=$FILENAME.crt` (client.crt) in the working directory